# How to check if record containing given word exists in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using PL/SQL, and I would like to check if a record exists in a table, I've tried using when exists or if not exists, but I end up with exception.

```
Select name from nameTable where name = nameFromArgument;
```

When the procedures starts, and I put in a wrong name, which is not in the database I'm getting an error, can't even handle it

I've tried something like this:

[PL/SQL check if query returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955025/pl-sql-check-if-query-returns-empty)

edit:

sorry, the select I've put before was just an example, the whole code [ sorry for names of variables... ] is here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SELLSTOCKS
( IloscAkcji IN NUMBER
, NazwaAkcji IN VARCHAR2
, IdRachunkuMaklerskiego IN NUMBER
)  AS
Bledna_ilosc EXCEPTION;
Bledna_nazwa EXCEPTION;
amount NUMBER;
stocksCash number;
idRachunku number;
stocksOnDealerSide number;
temp number;
tempus akcje_uzytkownika.nazwa % type;
BEGIN

--Select nazwa into tempus from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa = nazwaakcji;
--dbms_output.put_line(tempus);

  dbms_output.put_line('pre');
 select nazwa into tempus from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa = nazwaakcji;
 dbms_output.put_line('pre2');
 if tempus!=null then
    if ( iloscakcji> amount) THEN
  raise Bledna_ilosc;
  else
  select ilosc, cena_sztuki into amount, stockscash from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa= NazwaAkcji and id_rachunku_maklerskiego= IdRachunkuMaklerskiego;
 dbms_output.put_line(amount);
 dbms_output.put_line(stockscash);
  amount :=amount - iloscakcji;
  dbms_output.put_line(amount);
  update akcje_uzytkownika set ilosc= amount  where nazwa=NazwaAkcji and  id_rachunku_maklerskiego= idrachunkumaklerskiego;
  stockscash:= iloscAkcji * stocksCash;
  dbms_output.put_line(stockscash);
  select id_rachunku into idrachunku from rachunek_maklerski where id_rachunku_maklerskiego= idrachunkumaklerskiego; 
  temp:=SALDOUPDATE(stockscash, idrachunku);
  select ilosc into stocksOnDealerSide from akcje where nazwa = nazwaAkcji;
  stocksOnDealerSide := stocksondealerside+ iloscakcji;
  dbms_output.put_line(stocksOnDealerSide);
  update akcje set ilosc = stocksondealerside where nazwa = nazwaAkcji;
  end if;
  else
  dbms_output.put_line('post');
  end if;
EXCEPTION

  when Bledna_ilosc then
  dbms_output.put_line('Bledna ilosc');
  when Bledna_nazwa then
  dbms_output.put_line('Bledna nazwa');

END SELLSTOCKS;
```

I'm using oracle sql developer 1.5.5

```
BEGIN

--Select nazwa into tempus from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa = nazwaakcji;
--dbms_output.put_line(tempus);

  dbms_output.put_line('pre');
  select nazwa into tempus from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa = nazwaakcji;
  dbms_output.put_line('pre2');
  exception when no_data_found then
  raise no_data_found;

-- is this the right place?

  select ilosc, cena_sztuki into amount, stockscash from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa= NazwaAkcji and id_rachunku_maklerskiego= IdRachunkuMaklerskiego;
  dbms_output.put_line(amount);
  dbms_output.put_line(stockscash);
  amount :=amount - iloscakcji;
  dbms_output.put_line(amount);
  if ( iloscakcji> amount) THEN
  raise Bledna_ilosc;
  else
  update akcje_uzytkownika set ilosc= amount  where nazwa=NazwaAkcji and  id_rachunku_maklerskiego= idrachunkumaklerskiego;
  stockscash:= iloscAkcji * stocksCash;
  dbms_output.put_line(stockscash);
  select id_rachunku into idrachunku from rachunek_maklerski where id_rachunku_maklerskiego= idrachunkumaklerskiego; 
  temp:=SALDOUPDATE(stockscash, idrachunku);
```

........

Comment: Can you post what your actual code as your `select` seems to be missing an `into` clause. Can you also post the error and version of Oracle you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have four main things that are wrong (that I can see).

Firstly, `tempus!=null` will *never* work. As null is the absence of information you can't use the (in)equality operator when checking for nulls. Non-existence != non-existence. The correct syntax is to use [`is null`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/isnull.php), or in your case `tempus is not null`.

Secondly, `if ( iloscakcji> amount) THEN` will never evaluate to true as you don't initialise the value `amount`. A number cannot be greater than `null` as it doesn't exist. You have to initialise the variable `amount`. Maybe you meant the next select statement to be above this?

Thirdly, all of your `select ... into ...` statements are into single variables - not user defined table-types. This means that if 0 rows are returned by your query a `no_data_found` exception will be raised. If *more than one* row is returned a `too_many_rows` exception will be raised.

If you're only expecting at most one row then you don't need to worry too much about `too_many_rows`. This should really be enforced by a unique constraint on your table if possible. For example I would expect that `nazwa` should be unique on `akcje_uzytkownika`.

`no_data_found` is slightly different and is, I expect, what you meant to by `tempus != null`. Assuming that `amount` has been initialised to a value this can be re-written as:

```
begin

    -- do some stuff    
    begin

       select nazwa into tempus from akcje_uzytkownika where nazwa = nazwaakcji;

    -- If there-s no data catch the exception.
    exception when no_data_found then
       if ( iloscakcji > amount) then
          raise Bledna_ilosc;
       end if;

    end;        
    -- do some more stuff

end;
```

Lastly, and it's not really a mistake but, your code is fairly unreadable. I would consider using a lot more whitespace so that you can see what's going on.

P.S. By Oracle version I meant 11gr2 or 10g etc but it doesn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: wow, thank u very much for support u provide me, massive thing :), but I'm still suffering more problems, I'm quite sure that it is just syntax thing.

Comment: @iie, from your update it's because you're adding exceptions in the middle of the code. You have to nest PL/SQL blocks in order to get the exception handling in the correct place. I'll update my answer slightly.

Comment: ok ok, sorry don' bother, I've sort it out; THANK U ONCE AGAIN, great place with even better people ;)