# select row from multiple tables with least performance impact

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I have 2 tables with same columns . Eg  workInfo is one table and oldworkinfo is another table.   Columns can be - id , branch , product , Data . (id is unique primary key.)  when a transaction is completed it is deleted from workinfo and move to oldworkinfo .

I would like to write a query to optimally search from workinfo first and then oldworkinfo, as i have to perform some join operations in other tables.

ie first search in the workinfo table and if record is available return , otherwise search in oldworkinfo and return record. Following is a sample query i have written using union but this does search in both tables.

```
with squery as 
(select * from workinfo 
UNION ALL
select * from oldworkinfo)
Select * from squery where squery.id=Key;
```

Kindly suggest is this possible in a single query . I cannot use plsql option as overall joins and other queries become complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
with sub as
(select * from workinfo wi where wi.id = mykey)
select * from sub
union all
select * from oldworkinfo owi where owi.id = mykey and not exists (select * from sub)
```

edit : the `union all` is needed to search rows in both tables. By adding a `not exists` clause to the query on `oldworkinfo` , you ensure that you select its data only when the is no data in `workinfo`.

The working query would then be `select * from workinfo where id=mykey union all select * from oldworkinfo where id=mykey and not exists (select * from workinfo where id=mykey)`.

For performance and readability reasons, I used a `with` clause so that the query on `workinfo` is done only once.

Comment: tried following  --  with sub as
(select  id,Appdata1,Appdata3 from workinfo wi where wi.id = 46940)
select  id,Appdata1,Appdata3 from sub
union all
select  id,Appdata1,Appdata3 from oldworkinfo owi where owi.id = 46940 and not exists (select  id,Appdata1 from sub) .. Plan is still showing TABLE ACCESS OLDWORKINFO BY INDEX ROWID ...  in this 46940 is only available in the Workinfo table .

Comment: I don't think you can make the second table disappear from the plan if you use a single query. But I tested my solution on a similar case where the "old" table is not indexed : when looking for an ID that is in the usual table it returns immediately and doesn't spend time searching in the "old" table, and only when looking for an ID that is in the "old" table the search takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the main idea is to avoid unnecessary scan on a big table with historical data. This query can help avoid it:

```
select * from workinfo where id = Key
UNION ALL
select * from oldworkinfo where 
not exists (
    select null
    from workinfo wi where wi.id = Key
)
and id = Key
```

Comment: Hi stepan i have tried above query , but explain plan is still showing access to oldworkinfo. by ROWID  , when i tried for an id which is only in workinfo table.  May be this not possible .?

Comment: Hello Sims. I can't see any option to eliminate it from the plan totally in simple select, maybe handling of "no data found" exception like described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955025/pl-sql-check-if-query-returns-empty could help you.